# How to convolve the unit box function and the modified Bessel function of the second kind in 2D?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, convolution

In 1D the convolution of the unit box function and the modified Bessel function of the second kind $K_0(x)$ works very well.

```
Clear[f, g, h];
f[x_] := UnitBox[x];
g[x_] := BesselK[0, Abs[x]];
h = Convolve[f[y], g[y], y, x]
Plot[{f[x], g[x], h}, {x, -2, 2}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

However, when I try the same in 2D, the convolution doesn't work.

```
Clear[f, g, h];
f[x1_, x2_] := UnitBox[x1, x2];
g[x1_, x2_] := BesselK[0, Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2]];
h = Convolve[f[y1, y2], g[y1, y2], {y1, y2}, {x1, x2}]
```

How can I solve this problem in 2D? I am only interested in the analytical solution.

Comment: What happens if you try setting up the explicit integral?

Comment: The explicit integral `h = Integrate[f[y1, y2] * g[x1-y1, x2-y2], {y1, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y2, -Infinity, Infinity}]` doesn't work either.

Comment: Then it seems likely that *Mathematica* cannot obtain a closed form solution.

Comment: Maybe have a look at Schwarz Christoffel map. See also here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111479/rounding-the-corners-of-a-shape/111521#111521 and `PolyMap[n_, z_] := z Hypergeometric2F1[1/n, 2/n, (n + 1)/n, z^n]`

Answer (score 1):

When you say the 1D convolution of the unit box function and the modified Bessel function of the second kind $K_0(x)$ works very well, I'm not sure what you mean—nor the intended application as $K_0(x)$ is complex for $x<0$.

Note you get a *different* answer if you restrict the range to [-1,1] in the explicit integral

```
Integrate[BesselK[0, x - y], {y, -1, 1}]
```

And this answer is just what you get from the indefinite integral.

Finally, a natural alternative to the 2D unit box is a circle (which generalises the unit interval)
, in which case you could use rotational symmetry to obtain the answer.

Comment: I am trying to solve the 2D screened Poisson equation for the unit box source function $f(x_1, x_2)$. The modified Bessel function of the second kind $K_0(|x|)$ is the fundamental solution of this equation. I need to convolve it with the source function in order to get the actual solution. By "works well", I meant that `Convolve[]` gives me an output which I can use for calculations and plotting (the green line on the plot). My actual problem requires the 2D unit box so a circle is not desirable. I agree, however, that it can be used as an approximation.

Comment: I have corrected my question by writing `BesselK[0, Abs[x]]` in 1D instead of just `BesselK[0, x]`. So there should be no problems with $x < 0$. In 2D it has already been taken into account `BesselK[0, Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2]]`. I am still wondering why the same convolution cannot be calculated in 2D?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that *Mathematica* just doesn't know a closed form, @Pavlo? In which case, can you not use a numerical method instead?

Comment: @J.M. I agree that it could very likely be the case. On the other hand, is there a workaround to obtain the analytical solution? I have already solved this problem numerically but it's quite difficult to analyze the influence of different parameters on the final result.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this suffices:

```
f[x_, y_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  UnitBox[s, t] BesselK[0, 
    Sqrt[(x - s)^2 + (y - s)^2]], {s, -Infinity, 
   Infinity}, {t, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Visualizing:

```
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 25]
```

Plot could be improved but I do not have time at present.

[image]

Comment: Nice idea to use a numerical method to get an idea what the solution looks like. But shouldn't it be `y-t` in the `Sqrt` expression inside `NIntegrate`? Also visually i would expect the solution to resemble more a square than a diagonal line.