# Rounding the Corners of a Shape

Tags: graphics, regions, polygons

I was wondering whether there is an option in *Mathematica* that enables me to smooth the corners of a shape. The example I want to start with is the pentagon.

This can be crudely specified as

```
Graphics[
  Polygon[
    {{Sin[2π/5], Cos[2π/5]}, {Sin[4π/5], -Cos[π/5]}, 
     {-Sin[4π/5], -Cos[Pi/5]}, {-Sin[2π/5], Cos[2π/5]}, 
     {0, 1}}]
]
```

Unfortunately, I see no easy way that enables me to round the corners. What I am after is something that looks like this:

[image: Smooth Pentagon]

I would think *Mathematica* would have such a feature, but I can't seem to find anything. I'd be grateful if you could shine some light on this. Maybe this isn't as trivial as it seems.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### UPDATE:

The previous version of my answer worked, but did not give control on the rounding radius, nor did it fully work with as a starting point for a geometric region for further calculations. Here is a version that is still based on spline curves, but it gives **full control over the corner rounding radius**. It also returns a `FilledCurve` object that in my opinion is easier to style and can also be **discretized reliably** to use in further calculations.

```
Clear[splineRoundedNgon]
splineRoundedNgon[n_Integer /; n >= 3, roundingRadius_?(0 <= # <= 1 &)] :=
  Module[{vertices, circleCenters, tangentPoints, splineControlPoints},
   vertices = CirclePoints[n];
   circleCenters = CirclePoints[1 - Sec[Pi/n] roundingRadius, n];
   tangentPoints =
   {
    Table[RotationMatrix[2 i Pi/n].{circleCenters[[1, 1]], vertices[[1, 2]]}, {i, 0, n - 1}],
    Table[RotationMatrix[2 i Pi/n].{circleCenters[[-1, 1]], vertices[[-1, 2]]}, {i, 1, n}]
   };
   splineControlPoints = Flatten[Transpose[Insert[tangentPoints, vertices, 2]], 1];
   FilledCurve@BSplineCurve[splineControlPoints, SplineClosed -> True]
]
```

Here's the obligatory animation :-)

```
Animate[
 Graphics[
  {EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.01], Black}], FaceForm[Darker@Green], 
   splineRoundedNgon[5, radius]}
 ],
 {{radius, 0, "Rounding\nradius"}, 0, 1}
]
```

[image: animation of rounding]

And here is an example of a **discretized region** obtained from it:

```
DiscretizeGraphics[splineRoundedNgon[5, 0.3], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001]
```

[image: discretized region]

Such regions can be used e.g. as **domains for plotting** and in `NDSolve` calculations. For instance:

```
Plot3D[
  y Sin[5 x] + x Cos[7 y], {x, y} ∈ DiscretizeGraphics@splineRoundedNgon[5, 0.4]
]
```

[image: plot using region as domain]

---

You can also create a spline curve to get a bit more roundness in the corners than allowed by `JoinedForm`. You need to double each control point in your spline definition to have the spline "hug" the points more closely. This is conveniently wrapped up in the `roundRegPoly` helper function below:

```
Clear[roundRegPoly]
roundRegPoly[n_Integer /; n >= 3] :=
 FilledCurve@BSplineCurve[
   Flatten[#, 1] &@Transpose[{#, #}] &@CirclePoints[n],
   SplineClosed -> True
 ]

Graphics[
  {Darker@Green, EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.01], Black}], roundRegPoly[5]},
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is an excellent result. $+1$ upvote. I would also like to ask, as per my comment to C. E, how I would go about actually telling Mathematica that this is the domain that I want to work with for `NDSolve`. I'm ideally hoping to specify the above rounded pentagon as a domain $D$. In other words, I want to write $D= \cdots$. Usually I will write `D=Polygon[...]` but this won't work here. I apologise if this is a difficult question to ask. I've tried `D = roundRegPoly[5]` with no success.

Comment: @MrS100 Try using `DiscretizeGraphics@roundRegPoly[5]` as your region in `NDSolve`. It works as a plotting region: `Plot3D[1, {x, y} ∈ DiscretizeGraphics[roundRegPoly[5], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01]]` returns [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pFTvQ.png).

Comment: I'll give it a go now - thanks for the prompt response. I'll let you know the outcome

Comment: Works almost perfectly. The only flaw is that for some reason the bottom verticies of the polygon are not rounded. This is the case if I run `Plot3D[1, {x, y} ∈ DiscretizeGraphics[roundRegPoly[5], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01]]`. In your image above the bottom corners are rounded so I wonder why this is happening.

Comment: @MrS100 That's odd. I am packing up to leave my office for the day, so I won't be able to test this immediately, but I'll look into it.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for looking into this for me. I shall mark this answer as accepted. I'll let you know if I have any luck.

Comment: @MrS100 Your trouble comes from the fact that `DiscretizeGraphics` seems to always miss the first or last point of a `BSplineCurve`, as you can see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101796/9490)

Comment: @MrS100 - if you modify MarcoB's code to use the discretizable bspline that I made in that post then it works great, code [here](http://pastebin.com/raw/iCtbd6Qn)

Comment: Thanks JasonB, this works very well. This seems be everything I am after. Thanks a million!

Comment: @MrS100 Take a look at the update solution I added to the answer above. It should be more complete: it has adjustable rounding radius, and it can be discretized directly with no artifacts.

Comment: @JasonB Thank you for the pointers; I added an alternative approach that returns a `FilledCurve` generated from the spline, which seems to discretize fine at least in 10.4.

Comment: This is superb. The customisation with the rounding radius is really beneficial. Top answer!

Answer (score 20):

Just wanted to add purely mathematical approach using complex mapping technique.

```
 PolyMap[n_, z_] := z Hypergeometric2F1[1/n, 2/n, (n + 1)/n, z^n]
(* Integrate[1/(1 - ξ^n)^(2/n), {ξ, 0, z}] *) 

g = GraphicsGrid[
Table[
 ParametricPlot[
  z = PolyMap[n, r (Cos[t] + I Sin[t])]; {Re[z], Im[z]}, 
   {t, 0, 2 π}, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False] /. 
   Line[l_List] :> {{Lighter[ColorData[3, "ColorList"][[n]]], Polygon[l]}, {Red, Thick, Line[l]}}, 
 {n, 3, 8}, {r, 0.799, 1., 0.1}], 
ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image: some examples]

Comment: This is excellent $+1$ upvote!

Comment: For those who are a bit mystified as to how this works, look up the Schwarz–Christoffel mapping.

Comment: That's strange: so many upvotes but I get errors instead of the output with version 10.4 on Win7 x64: [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GBtcm.png). Are you sure you have no mistakes in the code?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thank you for testing the code. Mysteriously one comma disappear when editing... Now the code is corrected!

Comment: Now it works, thank you. +1

Answer (score 17):

Since you mention that you want to use the rounded polygon in `NDSolve[]` as a region, you might want to look at the following construction:

```
With[{r = 1/5 (* rounding radius *)}, 
     rp = DiscretizeRegion[
          ImplicitRegion[RegionDistance[
          Polygon[CirclePoints[{1 - 2 Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[5]] r, π/10}, 5]], {x, y}] <=
          r Sqrt[(5 - Sqrt[5])/2], {x, y}], MaxCellMeasure -> 1/200]];

Graphics[{{Yellow, Polygon[CirclePoints[{1, π/10}, 5]]},
          {Opacity[2/3, Blue], MeshPrimitives[rp, 2]}}]
```

[image: pentagon and its discretized rounded version]

Rescale/rotate/translate as needed.

Comment: I really like this solution. It is exceptionally well done. $+1$ upvote!

Comment: You can also use `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` and even get just a single `Polygon` with by applying `MeshPrimitives[#, 2] &` to the discretized region.

Comment: @kirma, I'll edit that in later, but on the other hand, for a single polygon with rounded corners, I won't even need the fancy region functionality. I can fall back on a little trig for that one. ;)

Comment: @J.M. Using "fancy region functionality" may sometimes be easier than thinking of trigonometry, though... ;)

Answer (score 16):

Here is a more general method for producing polygons with rounded corners. Using a bit of vector algebra and trigonometry, I came up with the following:

```
arcgen[{p1_, p2_, p3_}, r_, n_] :=
       Module[{dc = Normalize[p1 - p2] + Normalize[p3 - p2], cc, th}, 
              cc = p2 + r dc/EuclideanDistance[dc, Projection[dc, p1 - p2]];
              th = Sign[Det[PadRight[{p1, p2, p3}, {3, 3}, 1]]]
                   (π - VectorAngle[p3 - p2, p1 - p2])/(n - 1); 
              NestList[RotationTransform[th, cc],
                       p2 + Projection[cc - p2, p1 - p2], n - 1]]

roundedPolygon[Polygon[pts_?MatrixQ], r_?NumericQ, n : (_Integer?Positive) : 12] := 
               Polygon[Flatten[arcgen[#, r, n] & /@
               Partition[If[TrueQ[First[pts] == Last[pts]], Most, Identity][pts],
                         3, 1, {2, -2}], 1]]
```

Here, `r` is the rounding radius. and `n` controls the fineness of the component circle arcs. The resulting `Polygon[]` can then be fed into `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[]` or `DiscretizeRegion[]` if needed.

Here is the OP's original case:

```
DiscretizeRegion[roundedPolygon[Polygon[N[CirclePoints[{1, π/10}, 5], 20]], 1/5]]
```

[image: discretized rounded pentagon]

A concave example:

```
star = N[Riffle[CirclePoints[{1, π/10}, 5],
                RotateLeft @ CirclePoints[{4 Sin[π/10]^2, -π/10}, 5]], 20];

DiscretizeRegion[roundedPolygon[Polygon[star], 1/8]]
```

[image: rounded star]

Use the rounded star as a domain:

```
Plot3D[Sin[6 x + Sin[6 y]], {x, y} ∈ roundedPolygon[Polygon[N[star, 20]], 1/8]]
```

[image: wiggle my star]

Compare the result of `roundedPolygon[]` with the built-in `Rectangle[]`:

```
{Graphics[roundedPolygon[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {4, 0}, {4, 2}, {0, 2}} // N], 1/2],
          Frame -> True], 
 Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {4, 2}, RoundingRadius -> 1/2], Frame -> True]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: two corner-filleted rectangles]

As a final example demonstrating the flexibility of the routine, here is some Voronoi art:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> "MersenneTwister"];
            pts = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {50, 2}]];

BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> "ExtendedCA"];
            Graphics[{Directive[ColorData[61, RandomInteger[{1, 9}]], EdgeForm[Gray]],
                      roundedPolygon[#, 1/8]} & /@ MeshPrimitives[VoronoiMesh[pts], 2]]]
```

[image: rounded Voronoi tiles]

Comment: This is an excellent work of art. +1

Comment: @Runny, in that case, the time and paper spent deriving the required formulae were indeed well-spent. Thanks. :)

Comment: I edited to include a missing comma in `NestList` that was preventing it from running properly.

Comment: Huh, must've gotten removed while formatting. Thanks.

Comment: $+1$ from me. This is excellent! I very much like the generalisation of this to non regular polygons. I have to say, I am very happy with the quality of the answers I have received for my question. Thank you for posting this solution! The result looks really good.

Comment: @Mr S, you're welcome. :) This was a fun problem to think about, and this particular solution forced me to review vector stuff I learned many moons ago.

Comment: I'm having troubles with your code and squared lattices. Also, I wonder if it's possible to automatically fill the gaps between cells. If you have time, please take a look a this follow-up question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/213069/a-smooth-and-round-voronoi-mesh

Comment: @sam, "I wonder if it's possible to automatically fill the gaps between cells." - more work is needed for that; this procedure only processes individual polygons.

Answer (score 15):

`FilledCurve` will do the job because it can be styled by `JoinForm`:

```
Graphics[{
  EdgeForm[{JoinForm["Round"], Thickness[0.05]}],
  FilledCurve[Line /@ Partition[CirclePoints[5], 2, 2, 1]]
  }, PlotRange -> 1.2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

MarcoB found that this simpler version also works (see comments):

```
Graphics[{
  EdgeForm[{JoinForm["Round"], Thickness[0.05]}],
  FilledCurve[Line@CirclePoints[5]]
  }, PlotRange -> 1.2]
```

I also made a version where I combined a polygon with a list element but the list manipulation required is rather inelegant. It looks like this:

```
coords = ArrayPad[CirclePoints[5], {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}, "Periodic"];
coords = ArrayPad[coords, {{1, 1}, {0, 0}}, Mean[{coords[[1]], coords[[2]]}]];
Graphics[{
  Polygon[coords],
  JoinForm["Round"], Thickness[0.05],
  Line[coords]
  }]
```

Comment: Note that `Line@CirclePoints[5]` will work as well, instead of your partition expression (+1).

Comment: @MarcoB Actually you have to manipulate the coordinates to make that work, otherwise you will have one corner that is not rounded because the end will not be joined to the start by itself. I added my code for this to the end of my answer.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear: I meant to say that `Graphics[{EdgeForm[{JoinForm["Round"], Thickness[0.05]}], FilledCurve[Line@CirclePoints[5]]}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]]` should work too. This is [the output I get on 10.4](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kvPu3.png), which seems to me to have all corners rounded.

Comment: @MarcoB Actually I see now that you wrote "instead of...". I was so wrapped up in my thinking that I missed that part of the sentence/jumped to my conclusion.

Comment: This is a superb answer and is exactly what I'm looking for. $+1$ upvote! However, I'm hoping to use `NDSolve` with this as my domain but I'm unsure on what I should specify my domain as using the above. Is there a way of specifying this as a set of points rather than a graphics object? I'm trying to do `NDSolve[eqn,u, {x,y}\[Element]D]` where $D$ is the pentagon above with rounded corners. I'm just wondering how I should define $D$ using the above graphics object.

Comment: J. M. solved it, as you have seen :)