# Schwarz-Christoffel maps from unit disk to regular polygons visualization

Tags: plotting, complex, geometry, code-request

The function $$F(z)=\int_0^{z}(1-\zeta^n)^{-\frac{2}{n}}d\zeta$$ maps the open unit disk $\Bbb{D}=\{z\in\Bbb{C} : |z|\lt 1\}$ conformally on to the interior of a regular polygon with $n$ sides.
How can I visualize the images of circles $C_r=\{re^{i\theta} : 0\le\theta\le 2\pi\}$ with $0\lt r\lt 1$ under $F$ ?
I have never use Mathematica to do something like this. So I appreciate any thing that you can do related to this.

Comment: Take a look at this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15637/plotting-complex-numbers-as-an-argand-diagram/15643#15643

Comment: @Artes: I looked at the linked question and tried to work along those answer, but could not succeed. Everything I tried runs long time and give back some error.

Comment: See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111521) as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a working example. We set up a the function `F` (only a rather coarse numerical approximation to the integral is used). Afterwards, we plot it with `ParametricPlot`. The function `ReIm` converts complex numbers to 2-dimensional vectors; otherwise, `ParametricPlot` won't plot anything.

```
n = 5;
F[z_?NumericQ] :=  ReIm[NIntegrate[Power[(1. - (t z)^n), -2/n] z, {t, 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 4]]
ParametricPlot[
 F[r Exp[I s]], {s, -Pi, Pi}, {r, 0., 1.},
 Mesh -> {6 n - 1, 20},
 PlotPoints -> {6 n - 1, 20}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 1
 ]
```

[image]

**Edit:** As Carl Woll pointed out, the can obtain the integral symbolically. So let's generated a more accurate version of `F`. (Warning: This will take a while.)

```
Block[{z, n}, 
  F = {z, n} \[Function] 
    Evaluate[Integrate[Power[(1 - (t z)^n), -2/n] z, {t, 0, 1},
    Assumptions -> n > 0] /. ConditionalExpression[a_, b___] :> a
     ]
  ];
```

The advantage is that the drawing is now much quicker.

```
n = 7;
m = 6;
ParametricPlot[ReIm[F[r Exp[I s], n]], {s, -Pi, Pi}, {r, 0, 1},
 Mesh -> {m n - 1, 20},
 PlotPoints -> {m n + 1, 20},
 MaxRecursion -> 2
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: A couple suggestions. 1. You can symbolically integrate to obtain `t Hypergeometric2F1[1/n,2/n,1+1/n,t^n]` 2. I would use the equivalent `ParametricPlot[F[r Exp[I s]], ..]` instead.

Comment: Ah, the symbolic computation finally finishes! I did not expect that!

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed and helpful answer. I appreciate it very much. These days I am studying Schwarz-Christoffel mappings and these transformations are bit difficult understand as they re given by integrals. For example map from the unit dist to interior of a Pentagram has the form $$\int_0^z\dfrac{(1-z^5)^{2/5}}{(1+z^5)^{4/5}}dz.$$ Therefore I am curious that; Is there any way that we can do this visualization with the integral representation of a function $F$ ?

Comment: @Bumblebee, you can, but it's going to be slow since you need to integrate a function with singularities over the complex domain. But, since your particular example has a nice closed form, it would be a shame not to use it: `With[{n = 15}, ParametricPlot[With[{z = r Exp[I s]}, ReIm[z AppellF1[1/5, -2/5, 4/5, 6/5, z^5, -z^5]]], {s, -Pi, Pi}, {r, 0., 1.}, Mesh -> {10 n - 1, 20}, PlotPoints -> {10 n - 1, 20}, MaxRecursion -> 1]]`