# Independent RoundingRadius specifications for all corners

Tags: graphics, regions, geometry

I need help creating a `Rectangle` (or `Framed` object) where the roundness of each corner is specified separately. For example, I would like to create a `Rectangle` (or `Framed` object) having the left corners with `RoundingRadius` of 0 and the right corners with a `RoundingRadius` of 5.

Specifying the 'four' line styles separately would also be helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update:** Generalizing the ideas behind methods 1 and 2 to round the corners of arbitrary convex polygons:

```
ClearAll[inSphere, rndCorners]
inSphere[{p1_, p2_, p3_}, rad_] := Module[{rl = Min[ArcLength[Line[{p1, p2}]], 
    ArcLength[Line[{p2, p3}]], rad + rad/Sin[VectorAngle[p1 - p2, p2 - p3]/2]]},
  MeshCoordinates @ DiscretizeRegion @ 
   Insphere[{p2, p2 + rl Normalize[p3 - p2], p2 + rl Normalize[p1 - p2] }]]

inSphere[{p1_, p2_, p3_}, 0 | 0.] := {p2}

rndCorners[pts : {{_, _} ..}, r_List] := Module[{pn = Partition[RotateLeft@pts, 3, 1, 1]}, 
   ConvexHullMesh[Join @@ MapThread[inSphere, {pn, r}]]]

rndCorners[pts : {{_, _} ..}, r_] := rndCorners[pts, ConstantArray[r, Length@pts]]

rndCorners[p_Polygon, r_] := rndCorners[p[[1]], r]
rndCorners[s_Rectangle, r_] := rndCorners[Tuples[Transpose[{##}]& @@ s][[{1, 3, 4, 2}]], r]
```

***Caveat:*** Input radii are modified to ensure that, given the angles between and lengths of consecutive edges, the inscribed circles do not go outside the triangles formed by the coordinates of edge pairs. This restriction rules out getting a circle from a regular polygon using a very large radius.

***Examples:***

```
rndCorners[Rectangle[{0, 10}, {30, 30}], 5]
```

[image]

```
rndCorners[Rectangle[{0, 10}, {30, 30}], {0, 1, 3, 50000}]
```

[image]

```
rndCorners[Rectangle[{0, 10}, {30, 30}], {2, 0, 4, 0.}]
```

[image]

```
rndCorners[Polygon[10 N @ CirclePoints[5]], 5]
```

[image]

```
rndCorners[Polygon[10 N @ CirclePoints[5]], Range[5]]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[777]
points = RandomReal[20, {12, 2}];
poly = MeshPrimitives[ConvexHullMesh[points], 2][[1]];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thin, Gray}], Opacity[.5, LightYellow], poly, 
  Opacity[.5, Blue], 
  MeshPrimitives[rndCorners[poly, RandomReal[{1, 5}, Length@poly[[1]]]], 2], 
  Opacity[1], Black, PointSize[Medium], Point@points}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

**1.** Using `BoundingRegion[#, "MinConvexPolygon"]&` with translated disks as input:

```
ClearAll[roundCorners]
roundCorners[r_Rectangle, radii_] := 
  Module[{c = Tuples[Transpose[{##}] & @@ r][[{1, 3, 4, 2}]] - 
     {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}} radii},
    BoundingRegion[Join @@ MapThread[If[N[#2] == 0., {#}, 
         MeshCoordinates@BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@Disk[##]] &,
       {c, radii}], "MinConvexPolygon"]]
```

The second argument `radii` is a 4-tuple specifying the corner radii in counter-clockwise order starting from the bottom-left corner.

***Examples:***

```
roundCorners[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}], {.3, .5, .2, .4}]
```

[image]

```
roundCorners[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}], {0, .2, 0., .4}]
```

[image]

```
roundCorners[Rectangle[{0, 1}, {3, 2}], {.5, .1, .2, .5}]
```

[image]

```
roundCorners[Rectangle[{0, 10}, {30, 20}], {5, 1, 2, 5}]
```

[image]

```
rect = Rectangle[{0, 10}, {30, 20}];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], LightGray, rect, EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], 
  Opacity[.5, LightBlue], MeshPrimitives[roundCorners[rect, {5, 1, 2, 5}], 2]}]
```

[image]

**2.** `ConvexHullMesh` of translated disks:

```
ClearAll[roundCorners2]
roundCorners2[r_Rectangle, radii_] := 
 Module[{ctrs = Tuples[Transpose[{##}] & @@ r][[{1, 3, 4, 2}]] -
   {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}} radii},
  ConvexHullMesh[Join @@ (MapThread[
      If[N[#2] == 0., {#}, MeshCoordinates @ BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@Disk[##]] &, 
      {ctrs, radii}])]]
```

***Example:***

```
roundCorners2[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}], {0, .2, 0., .4}]
```

[image]

**3.** Using `BSplineCurve` + `FilledCurve`

```
ClearAll[roundCorners3]
roundCorners3[r_Rectangle, radii_] := 
 Module[{pts = Tuples[Transpose[{##}] & @@ r][[{1, 3, 4, 2}]], 
   offsets = {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}} radii, bc}, 
  bc = BSplineCurve[#[[FindShortestTour[#][[2, ;; -2]]]], 
      SplineKnots -> "Unclamped", SplineClosed -> True] &[
    Join @@ MapThread[Function[{x, y}, {x, x + y[[1]], x + y[[1]], x + y[[2]], 
        x + y[[2]]}], 
       {pts, {{#[[1]], 0}, {0, #[[2]]}} & /@ offsets}]];
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], Opacity[.5, LightBlue], FilledCurve@bc}]]
```

***Example:***

```
roundCorners3[Rectangle[{0, 10}, {30, 20}], {3, 4, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

### Update 3

This is my final update except for typo corrections. I hope it provides a useful answer to the OP's question.

I don't believe the OP's problem can be solved by fooling around with `RoundingRadius`. I think one needs to write a function that will generate a polygon that `Graphics` will render as a NURC (Non-Uniform-Rounded-Corners) rectangle and which will behave as such when given to the various region functions.

### Requirements

My goal is to implement a function that returns a polygon that will be rendered in graphics as a rectangle which can have  non-uniform rounded corners.

#### Arguments

- First two arguments are the same as for Rectangle: `{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}`.
  Function should be able to build a rectangle with normal sharp corners.
- Third argument is a list of the four corner radii: `{rtl, rtr, rbl, rbr}`.
  `rtl` is the radius of the top-left corner.
  `rtr` is the radius of the top-right corner.
  `rbl` is the radius of the bottom-left corner.
  `rbr` is the radius of the bottom-right corner.
- Fourth argument, `n`, is the number of line segments making up the quarter circles composing the corners.
  Exception: a corner with radius zero ignores this argument and consists of a single point.
  Default value is 10.
- No optional arguments

#### Argument consistency

- First two arguments
  Same consistency requirements as Rectangle: `xmin ≤ xmax && ymin ≤ ymax`.
- Third argument
  Each element must be a non-negative numeric quantity.
  `rtl + rtr ≤ xmax -  xmin`
  `rbl + rbr ≤ xmax - xmin`
  `rtl + rbl ≤ ymax - ymin`
  `rtr + rbr ≤ ymax - ymin`
- Fourth argument
  Integer satisfying `n > 1`.

#### Alternative ways to specify corner radii

Besides a list of the four corner radii given in the fixed order stated under *Arguments*, for convenience, the following alternatives should be accepted:

- Single numeric: all corners given the same radius.
- Single rule: corner *name –> radius*.
  Remaining corners given radius zero.
  Valid corner names: `"TopLf", "TopRt", "BtmLf", "BtmRt"`.
- List containing at least one and at most four rules.
  Rules may be given in any order.

### Proof of concept computation

I originally posted this to serve as a kind of place holder. Something for people to read while I was developing the real answer. I am leavening it the answer because I think makes my approach pretty clear to casual reader who views the full answer as living deep in TL;DR territory.

```
nurcRect =
  Module[{corners, cornerPts},
    With[{xmin = 0, ymin = 0, xmax = 200, ymax = 100},
      cornerPts[corner_] :=
        N[corner["xy"] + {corner["r"] Cos[#], corner["r"] Sin[#]} & /@
          Subdivide[corner["α"], corner["β"], corner["n"]]];
       With[{rtl = 10, rtr = 20, rbl = 40, rbr = 30, n = 9},
         corners = {
           (* top right corner *) 
           <|"xy" -> {xmax - rtr, ymax - rtr}, "r" -> rtr, "α" -> 0, "β" -> π/2, 
             "n" -> n|>,
           (* top-left corner *)
           <|"xy" -> {xmin + rtl, ymax - rtl}, "r" -> rtl, "α" -> π/2, "β" -> π, 
             "n" -> n|>,
           (* bottom left corner *)
           <|"xy" -> {xmin + rbl, ymin + rbl}, "r" -> rbl, "α" -> π, "β" -> 3 π/2, 
             "n" -> n|>,
           (* bottom right corner *)
           <|"xy" -> {xmax - rbr, ymin + rbr}, "r" -> rbr, "α" -> 3 π/2, "β" -> 2 π, 
             "n" -> n|>} ;
         Polygon[Catenate[cornerPts /@ corners]]]]];

Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], FaceForm[], nurcRect}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: poly]

```
Through[{RegionBounds, Area}[nurcRect]]
```

> `{{{0., 200.}, {0., 100.}}, 19344.3}`

### Notes

- NURC = Non-Uniform-Rounded-Corners
- To get the more specialized versions `nurcRectangle` to to looked at first by the kernel during evaluation, the main definition of `nurcRectangle` which does almost all the error checking and which requires all four corner radii to be explicitly given must appear last in the symbol's down-values list. Therefore, the more specialized versions are defined before the main version in the code. Unfortunately this is not the best order for presentation.

### Implementation

**Messages**

```
Messages[nurcRectangle] =.
nurcRectangle::badarg = "Argument `1` can not contain `2`";
nurcRectangle::badn = "In argument 4 condition n > 1 is not satisfied";
nurcRectangle::notsat = "Condition `1` is not satisfied";
nurcRectangle::badnrule = "In argument 3 the rule `1` is invalid";
```

#### Definitions allowing alternative specifications for argument 3

Give only one numeric radius specification; all corners will use this specification. This is a convenient way to specify a ordinary rounded corner rectangle.

```
nurcRectangle[{xmin_, ymin_}, {xmax_, ymax_}, r_?NumericQ, n_: 10] :=
  nurcRectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}, {r, r, r, r}, n]
```

Give only one radius specification of the form *name -> radius*. This is the same as giving the specification: *{name -> radius}*.

```
nurcRectangle[{xmin_, ymin_}, {xmax_, ymax_}, rule_Rule, n_: 10] :=
  nurcRectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}, {rule}, n]
```

Give a list containing at least one and at most four radii specifications as rules of the form *name -> radius*.  If two or more rules have the same name token, only the last of these rules will be used. This is only way in which the order of the rules matters.

```
With[
  {ordering =
     AssociationThread[{"TopLf", "TopRt", "BtmLf", "BtmRt"}, Range[4]]},
  nurcRectangle[
    {xmin_, ymin_}, {xmax_, ymax_}, arg3 : {Repeated[_Rule, 4]}, n_: 10] :=
    Module[{given, names, radii},
      given = Association @@ arg3;
      names = Keys[given];
      If[Check[
           With[{allnames = Keys[ordering]},
             Do[
               If[Not[MemberQ[allnames, nm]], 
                 Message[nurcRectangle::badnrule, nm -> given[nm]]], 
               {nm, names}]],
           True,
           {nurcRectangle::badnrule}],
        Return[$Failed]];
      radii = ConstantArray[0, 4];
      Set[radii[[#1]], #2] & @@@ ({ordering[#], given[#]} & /@ names);
      nurcRectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}, radii, n]]]
```

#### Helper functions

There is nothing fancy here. Argument checking is just a matter of slogging through all the constraints placed on the arguments and making sure they are met. If any of the constraints fail to be be met, the function `nurcArgChecker` issues an error message and returns `False`; otherwise it returns `True`.

This is one of those situations where using the seldom used functions,`TrueQ` and `Return`, makes sense because their use improves readability of the code.

```
nurcArgChecker[
  {xmin_, ymin_}, {xmax_, ymax_}, {rtl_, rtr_, rbl_, rbr_}, n_: 10] := (
  If[Not[TrueQ[rtl >= 0]],
    Message[nurcRectangle::badarg, 3, rtl]; Return[False]];
  If[Not[TrueQ[rtr >= 0]],
    Message[nurcRectangle::badarg, 3, rtr]; Return[False]]; 
  If[Not[TrueQ[rbl >= 0]],
    Message[nurcRectangle::badarg, 3, rbl]; Return[False]];
  If[Not[TrueQ[rbr >= 0]],
    Message[nurcRectangle::badarg, 3, rbr]; Return[False]];
  If[Not[TrueQ[n[[0]] === Integer]],
    Message[nurcRectangle::badarg, 4, n]; Return[False]];
  If[Not[TrueQ[xmin < xmax]],
    Message[nurcRectangle::notsat, "xmin < xmax"]; Return[False]];
  If[Not[TrueQ[ymin < ymax]],
    Message[nurcRectangle::notsat, "ymin < ymax"]; Return[False]];
  If[Not[TrueQ[xmin < xmax]],
    Message[nurcRectangle::notsat, "xmin < xmax"]; Return[False]];
  If[Not[TrueQ[rtl + rtr <= xmax - xmin]],
    Message[nurcRectangle::notsat, "rtl + rtr <= xmax - xmin"]; Return[False]];
  If[Not[TrueQ[rbl + rbr <= xmax - xmin]],
    Message[nurcRectangle::notsat, "rbl + rbr <= xmax - xmin"]; Return[False]];
  If[Not[TrueQ[rtl + rbl <= ymax - ymin]],
    Message[nurcRectangle::notsat, "rtl + rbl <= ymax - ymin"]; Return[False]];
  If[Not[TrueQ[rtr + rbr <= ymax - ymin]],
    Message[nurcRectangle::notsat, "rtr + rbr <= ymax - ymin"]; Return[False]];
  If[Not[TrueQ[n > 1]], Message[nurcRectangle::badn]; Return[False]];
  True)
```

Given an association describing the corner, `nurcCornerPts` returns a list of points comprising the points that form the corner in the NURC rectangle.

```
nurcCornerPts[corner_] :=
  If[corner["r"] == 0,
    {N[corner["xy"]]},
    N[corner["xy"] + {corner["r"] Cos[#], corner["r"] Sin[#]} & /@
      Subdivide[corner["α"], corner["β"], corner["n"]]]]
```

#### Main function

This version of `nurcRectangle` requires its third argument to be a list of four numerical quantities. They must given in the fixed order and satisfy the requirements stated in the section **Requirements**.

```
nurcRectangle[
   {xmin_, ymin_}, {xmax_, ymax_}, {rtl_, rtr_, rbl_, rbr_}, n_: 10] /;
    nurcArgChecker[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}, {rtl, rtr, rbl, rbr}, n] := 
  Module[{corners},
    corners = {
      (* top right corner *) 
      If[rtr == 0,
        <|"xy" -> {xmax, ymax}, "r" -> rtr|>,
        <|"xy" -> {xmax - rtr, ymax - rtr}, "r" -> rtr, 
          "α" -> 0, "β" -> π/2, "n" -> n|>],
      (* top-left corner *)
      If[rtl == 0,
        <|"xy" -> {xmin, ymax}, "r" -> rtl|>,
        <|"xy" -> {xmin + rtl, ymax - rtl}, "r" -> rtl, 
          "α" -> π/2, "β" -> π, "n" -> n|>],
      (* bottom left corner *)
      If[rbl == 0,
        <|"xy" -> {xmin, ymin}, "r" -> rbl|>,
        <|"xy" -> {xmin + rbl, ymin + rbl}, "r" -> rbl, 
          "α" -> π, "β" -> 3 π/2, "n" -> n|>],
      (* bottom right corner *)
      If[rbr == 0,
        <|"xy" -> {xmax, ymin}, "r" -> rbr|>,
        <|"xy" -> {xmax - rbr, ymin + rbr}, "r" -> rbr, 
          "α" -> 3 π/2, "β" -> 2 π, "n" -> n|>]};
    Polygon[Catenate[nurcCornerPts /@ corners]]]
```

### Examples of use

Showing that `nurcRectangle` can reproduce the result of the proof-of-concept computation.

```
With[
  {rect1 = nurcRectangle[{0, 0}, {200, 100}, {10, 20, 40, 30}, 9],
   rect2 =
     nurcRectangle[
      {0, 0}, {200, 100}, 
      {"TopRt" -> 20, "BtmRt" -> 30, "TopLf" -> 10, "BtmLf" -> 40}, 9]},
   GraphicsRow[
     Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], FaceForm[], #}, Frame -> True] & /@ 
       {rect1, rect2},
     ImageSize -> 500]]
```

[image: nurc_rects]

Half-discs and quarter disks.

```
With[
  {rect1 = 
     nurcRectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}, {"TopRt" -> 1, "TopLf" -> 1}],
   rect2 = 
     nurcRectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}, {"BtmLf" -> 1, "BtmRt" -> 1}]},
   GraphicsRow[
     Graphics[
       {EdgeForm[], FaceForm[Red], #},
       Frame -> True, 
       ImagePadding -> {{8, 3}, {12, 5}}] & /@ {rect1, rect2},
   Spacings -> -20,
   ImageSize -> 500]]
```

[image: half_disks]

```
GraphicsGrid[
  Partition[
    Graphics[
      {EdgeForm[], FaceForm[Red], nurcRectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, # -> 1]}, 
      Frame -> True,
      ImagePadding -> {{18, 3}, {12, 10}}] & /@ 
      {"TopLf", "TopRt", "BtmLf", "BtmRt"}, 
    2],
  Spacings -> 6,
  ImageSize -> 350]
```

[image: quarter_disks]

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it is not too hard to modify `roundedPolygon[]` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111690) so that it can take different rounding radii for the corners:

```
arcgen[{p1_, p2_, p3_}, r_, n_] := Module[{cc, dc, th},
       If[r > 0,
          dc = Normalize[p1 - p2] + Normalize[p3 - p2];
          cc = p2 + r dc/EuclideanDistance[dc, Projection[dc, p1 - p2]];
          th = Sign[Det[PadRight[{p1, p2, p3}, {3, 3}, 1]]]
               (π - VectorAngle[p3 - p2, p1 - p2])/(n - 1);
          NestList[RotationTransform[th, cc], 
                   p2 + Projection[cc - p2, p1 - p2], n - 1],
          {p2}]]

roundedPolygon[Polygon[pts_?MatrixQ], rl_?VectorQ, n : (_Integer?Positive) : 12] := 
       Polygon[Flatten[MapThread[arcgen[##, n] &,
                                 {Partition[If[TrueQ[First[pts] == Last[pts]],
                                               Most, Identity][pts], 3, 1, {2, -2}],
                                  rl}], 1]] /; Length[rl] == Length[pts]

roundedPolygon[Rectangle[args___], rl_?VectorQ, n : (_Integer?Positive) : 12] :=
       Module[{perm = {1, 3, 4, 2}, poly},
              poly = Switch[Length[{args}],
                            0, Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}],
                            1, Polygon[Tuples[Transpose[{args, args + 1}]][[perm]]],
                            2, Polygon[Tuples[Transpose[{args}]][[perm]]],
                            _, Return[{}, Module]];
              roundedPolygon[poly, rl, n]] /; Length[rl] == 4

(* backwards compatibility with original implementation *)
roundedPolygon[p : (_Polygon | _Rectangle), r_?NumericQ,
               n : (_Integer?Positive) : 12] := 
roundedPolygon[p, ConstantArray[r, If[Head[p] === Rectangle, 4, Length[First[p]]]], n]
```

Using three of kglr's examples:

```
Graphics[roundedPolygon[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {0, 1}} // N],
                        {0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4}], Frame -> True]
```

[image: rounded rectangle with different corners]

```
Graphics[roundedPolygon[Polygon[{{0, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {0, 2}} // N],
                        {0.5, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5}], Frame -> True]
```

[image: another rounded rectangle]

```
Graphics[roundedPolygon[Rectangle[{0., 10}, {30, 30}], {2, 0, 4, 0}]]
```

[image: rectangle rounded at two corners]

A more complicated example:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42]; (* for reproducibility *)
            pts = MeshPrimitives[ConvexHullMesh[RandomReal[{-9, 9}, {11, 2}]], 2][[1, 1]]];

Graphics[{{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Dashed], Polygon[pts]},
          {roundedPolygon[Polygon[pts], 8 {0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5}]}}]
```

[image: random polygon with rounded corners]

Finally, a **concave** example:

```
star = N[Riffle[CirclePoints[{1, π/10}, 5],
                RotateLeft @ CirclePoints[{4 Sin[π/10]^2, -π/10}, 5]], 20];

Graphics[roundedPolygon[Polygon[star], PadRight[{}, 10, {1/20, 1/8}]]]
```

[image: rounded star]

I do not believe the other answers can handle this case.